# Facebook like doesn't work in div

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

I'm using facebook like button on my blog I'm collect all social network like&share buttons in one div and I'm open that div with toggle link. Twitter and google+ buttons work well but facebook like button doesn't work on firefox however it works on chrome. By the way if I'm not use div its also works correctly on firefox. I don't know where is the problem.

I think reason is javascript code execute on page load and div's property is display:none; maybe its effects the code.

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('.share').toggle();return false;"><b>Share</b></a>
<div class="share">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=API_ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="url" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a lt-character missing in opening div

Comment: I guess its due to copy & paste, still I have same problem.

Comment: I assume you have replace API_ID for this copy/paste? Is there any network activity after clicking the div? You can check that with the Network pane of your developer tools.

Comment: Yes dude I'm using this button for months today I put it in a div and now it doesn't work.

Comment: If you provide a link to the page where the button isn't working then I'll take a look and try to fix your problem.

Comment: http://www.kodseven.com/blog-37-Tasarimcilar-icin-5-Flat-ikon-Paketi.html this page or else doesn't matter bottom of the page next to dislike button click "Paylaş ›" link which means share in my language you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you go through the documentation here and make sure you have done it properly. 
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/`. Also, in your code. The problem is with how the fb-root is defined. It is clearly mentioned in FB documentation that it should the first thing after body tag and for sure it is not inside any other div. 
Then you should define the JS needed to fetch FB library.

After that, put your button inside any div you like. There should not be any problem with that.

To be more clear:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=API_ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<!-- Anything should be after this -->

<a href="#" onClick="$('.share').toggle();return false;"><b>Share</b></a>
<div class="share">
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="url" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data- width="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

I think you wanted the 'like' button to be inside the div, not the whole instantiation of FB JS SDK which was the mistake in your approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow dude you right besides I repeat the code for fb comments I remove it also and I did what you mention now it works thank you so much.